# phpStorm asks for php-cgi built interpreter. How to make php as fast cgi?

Tags: php, apache, curl, phpstorm, osx-yosemite

I am new to OS X environment. I need to setup php dev environment so I've phpStorm IDE + php 5.4 (cli) with xdebug 2.2.3 + apache 2.1 installed and configured.

[image]

When I tried to build my project, I got an error as

> php-cgi not found

I've read few solution and tried to make a facts php but then I got cURL error saying that

> reinstall libcurl as easy.h should be in /use/include/curl.

I'm having `easy.h` at same location. How do I make through this step ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Found it as, I needed to install Xcode for Command Line.

```
$bash~# xcode-select --install
```

Now, another problem is mysql header files can't be found at

**/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24/include/mysql**