# PhpStorm : Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found S

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

So PHPstorm is running the PHP code fine in its console when I click run; that's great but I want to see it in the browser.

So, I created a Built in Server inside project.

[image: A screenshot of error and configuration]

Now, when I clicked on Run -> Run Project, I'm getting error as:

> "Error in argument 1, char 2: option not found S"

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have pointed your PHP Interpreter to `php-cgi` while it should be just `php`...

`php-cgi` does not support `-S` option -- that's exactly what message says. You can verify that with `php-cgi -h` command (and compare to `php -h` output).

Comment: Not setting it to php-cgi will lead to another error. Here - [PHP-CGI Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274939/phpstorm-asks-for-php-cgi-built-interpreter-how-to-make-php-as-fast-cgi)

Comment: AFAIK this means that you need to find another php build (or build your own from the sources). For example: try one that comes with MAMP .. or maybe the one that can be installed with `homebrew`